# Ejecutar un print si la fecha de hoy está entre otras 2 fechas

Tags: python, date, async-await

suena sencillo, pero para mi no lo fue
quiero que si hoy estamos entre 1/7/2021 y 4/7/2021
se ejecute un print con un mensaje
esto fue lo que intenté

```
intervalo = date(2021,7,2) and date(2021,7,3) and date(2021,7,4)
hoy = date.today()
    
async def mensajealeatorio(ctx):
        if hoy == intervalo:
            await print("Hola")
            time.sleep(random.randint(10,40))
        else:
            await print("La fecha de hoy no está dentro del intervalo")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los datos de tipo *datetime* también soportan operaciones de comparación, por lo que la lógica sería la misma que al comprobar que un numero esta en un rango determinado `1<n<4`.

```py
ini = date(2021,7,1)
fin = date(2021,7,4)

now = date.today()
async def mensajealeatorio(ctx):
        if ini< now <fin:
            await print("Hola")
            time.sleep(random.randint(10,40))
        else:
            await print("La fecha de hoy no está dentro del intervalo")
```

Para este caso no podemos usar `now in range(ini,fin)` pues el `range()` espera numero de tipo entero y no datetime.